# Drupal jQuery error on form #states

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, form-api

I have a strange jQuery error when I try to put a #states on a field :

```
$payment_form['totalite'] = array(
'#type' => 'radio',
'#title' => "Payer la totalité",
'#weight' => -1,
'#name' => 'commerce_payment[totalite]',
'#states' => array(
  'unchecked' => array(
    //':input[name="commerce_payment[partagez]"]' => array('checked' => false),
    )
  )
);
```

And this throw me this error :

```
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why do you have this jquery mayor version?. Your mayor jquery version should be jQuery v1.10.2. Are you adding your own jquery library?

Comment: install jquery_update module